# How to call function only once when multiple subscribed variables are called together

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observer-pattern, observable

This is not specifically a technical question but I was curious what is the best approach to such a problem? Although I have this issue in Knockout, I'm sure the use case will be valid elsewhere too.

Lets say I have subscribed 2 variables, `simpleObserve1`, `simpleObserve2` so that every time their value changes, they call a function `resetAllValues()`.

```
var simpleObserve1 = ko.observable(0), // initial values
    simpleObserve2 = ko.observable(0); // initial values

var resetAllValues = function resetAllValues() {
    /* this function takes all observable values and resets them */
    {...}
}

simpleObserve1.subscribe(function(){
    resetAllValues();
});

simpleObserve2.subscribe(function(){
    resetAllValues();
});

simpleObserve1(5); // value changed anywhere in code
simpleObserve2(10); // value changed anywhere in code
```

2 questions here.

1. When resetAllValues() is called, it changes all subscribed values to 0, including `simpleObserve1` and `simpleObserve2`. This in turn calls `resetAllValues()` over and over again. How do I prevent this from going into an infinite loop?
2. What if I want to update both the variables together, but call the `resetAllValues()` only once?

I've tried to use the [knockout's dispose()](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) method to help me along, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

[Deferred Updates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html) might help you out. By using observables' values in a computed, knockout creates a subscription. By extending this computed, rapidly succeeding changes are combined in some sort of micro-task.

They prevent the looping behavior, but it's still kind of unclear how many updates are triggered. I.e.: when setting to `5` and `10` results in *1* or *2* computed updates. So I'm not entirely sure if this answers your question.

```js
var i = 0,
  simpleObserve1 = ko.observable(0), // initial values
  simpleObserve2 = ko.observable(0); // initial values

ko.computed(function resetAllValues() {
  console.log("Set " + ++i + ", before:");
  console.log("1: ", simpleObserve1());
  console.log("2: ", simpleObserve2());

  simpleObserve1(0);
  simpleObserve2(0);

  console.log("Set " + i + ", after:");
  console.log("1: ", simpleObserve1());
  console.log("2: ", simpleObserve2());

}).extend({
  deferred: true
});

simpleObserve1(5); // value changed anywhere in code
simpleObserve2(10); // value changed anywhere in code
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a higher order function `acceptXParams`, that will check if the number of params is equal to `fn.length` or an arbitrary number. If not, the original function won't be invoked:

```js
function acceptXParams(fn, numOfParams) {
  var numOfParams = numOfParams === undefined ? fn.length : numOfParams;
  
  return function() {
    if(arguments.length !== numOfParams) {
      return; 
    }
    
    return fn.apply(fn, arguments);
  }
}

/** example **/

function sum(a, b, c) {
  return a + b + c;
}

var sum3 = acceptXParams(sum);

console.log(sum3(1, 2, 3));

console.log(sum3(1, 2));

console.log(sum3(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

And a more sleek ES6 version `acceptXParams`:

```
const acceptXParams = (fn, numOfParams = fn.length) => 
    (...args) => 
        args.length === numOfParams ? fn(...args) : undefined;
```